# Script to split comma separated text?

Tags: powershell, scripting

I'm looking to create a simple script to do the following:

I have two text columns, one with a lot of names separated by commas and the other with a date i.e

```
col 1         col2
matt, john    12/11/2019
```

I want to convert this to the following:

```
col1          col2
matt          12/11/2019
john          12/11/2019
```

Would this be easy to do? I'm not very good with scripting...

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what the expected output should be, so this is for creating an array of objects you can easily display as table or write to file.

```
# simulating the text in a Here-string.
# If your input is in a file, use 
# $text = Get-Content -Path '<THE FILE>'

$text = @"
col 1         col2
matt, john    12/11/2019
"@ -split '\r?\n'

$result = $text | Select-Object -Skip 1 |  ForEach-Object {
    $names, $date = ($_ -replace ',\s+', ',') -split '\s+', 2
    foreach ($name in $names -split ',') {
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            'col1' = $name
            'col2' = $date
        }
    }
}
```

The result will be an array of **objects**, each having two properties: `col1` and `col2`

```
# Output on screen
$result

# output to CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\example.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Result on screen:

> ```
> col1 col2      
> ---- ----      
> matt 12/11/2019
> john 12/11/2019
> ```

Hope that helps